# Regex: Match url string in the middle of another string

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Learning regexp but currently I'm a bit stucked with such pattern..

I need to match my string inside url string, example:

If url contains string `'/example/regex'` it should return true.

```
/REGEXFOR:'/example/regex'/.test('http://test.com/example/regex/new') // => true
/REGEXFOR:'/example/regex'/.test('http://test.com/example/regex/new/boo') // => false
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your example. Is it right?

Comment: myRegexFor() is a function you created? What does it do?

Comment: sorry, updated a question

Comment: It still isn't clear in the question what you wish to do. Both the examples you listed _contains_ the string, but only one should be valid, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case using $ you can indicate the end of the regex

```
/\/example\/regex\/\w*$/.test('http:\/\/test.com\/example\/regex\/new') => true
/\/example\/regex\/\w*$/.test('http:\/\/test.com\/example\/regex\/new\/boo') => false
```

if you don't want any slash more use \w* for letters and numbers characters

Answer (score 0):

You just escape the backslash and you need to clean it a bit;

```
 /\/example\/regex/.test('http://test.com/example/regex/new/boo')
```

According to what you gave as examples, both should validate, though.

Comment: but this should return ``false``

Comment: Why should this return false? It contains '/example/regex'.